# Sniffing client to server socket communication

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, at-command, sniffer

I was developing an IoT application with a BBB and a Quectel GSM modem to send data over internet.
I configured the modem on the debian OS with PPP. Then with something similar to [this example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example) I stablished communication between my server and my client. Data was trivial, I send just a simple **"Close!"**, and receive a simple **"OK!"**. Sniffing the serial port, I was expecting something simpler, but here is what I saw:

BBB >> GSM modem

```
ATZ
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.comcel.com.co"
ATD*99***1#
~}#!}!}!} }4}"}&} } } } }%}&"}'}"}(}"0~~}#!}!}"} }4}"}&} }*} } }%}&"}'}"}(}"}>~~}#!}$}!} }(}#}$#,~~}#!}"}"} }.}"}&} }*} } }'}"}(}"P~! "?~xx/2~!-/~!
!~!
j~!

_3~~!E<@@_
_-7`99
}3BT~~!E<@@^
_-7`99
}3D~!E4@@e
_-7`:l5s
}3FGcE~!E:@@^
_-7`:l5d
}3FGcEClose!=~~!E4@@c
_-7`@l5
}3HcEh$~!E4@@b
_-7`@l5
}3HcE~!E4@@a
_-7`@l8
}3IycG~!E4@@`
_-7`@l8}1
}3Iyc~!E4@@_
_-7`Al9
}3I|c%~~!E4@@^
_-7`@l9}1
}3Sc
!~~!  "=~~!E4@@\
_-7`@l9}1
}3cws~
```

Modem >> BBB

```
+CFUN: 1

+CPIN: READY
ATZ

OK
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 

OK
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.comcel.com.co"

OK
ATD*99***1#

CONNECT
~}#!}!}!} }2}"}&} }*} } }#}$#}'}"}(}"U~~}#!}#}!} }*}"}&} }*} } lP~~}#!}"}"} }4}"}&} }*} } }%}&gHT}'}"}(}"Q~~}#!}!}!} }2}"}&} }*} } }#}$#}'}"}(}"U~~}#!}!}"} }.}"}&} }*} } }'}"}(}"~~!
H~~!
k~~!xx/~~!
-0~~!

xP`~~!

xP~~!E<@1-7
xPyCdOq x
d/2mQ~~!E<@1-7
xPyCdOq _x
d0N2~~!E4"@1Bw-7
xPzCdUrN
d0ev ~~!E7#@1Bs-7
xPzCdUrd
d0eOK!3~~!E4$@1Bu-7
xP}]CdU}1rN
d0e~
```

I'm familiar with those AT commands, the "Close!" is there, and on the other side the "OK! is there too, but I didn't expect all those strange characters. I must say that I'm not very familiar with low level development for the TCP/IP network model, but I've always thought that sockets communication was the lowest layer (not counting physical layers).

What am I missing and where can I find more info related to this topic?

Thank you.

Comment: What you're missing is that that TCP/IP is based on *packets* rather than simple byte streams... so likely the other data you're seeing is the various packet headers (for the PPP protocol, the IP packet headers, UDP (or TCP) packet headers, etc.  If you want to parse those you'll probably want to pick up a book on TCP/IP networking, but be aware that it will be a non-trivial task.  You might be better off using WireShark (or similar) to parse them for you.

Comment: If you can print that garbage in HEX you may discover those are bytes of the protocols' headers.

Comment: I'm not really assuming that's garbage, in fact those HEX bytes must be some kind of protocol headers, checksum, etc. The point is that I can't find to which protocol those bytes belong to, and it would be helpful to find some  info to understand what's really going on there